# Why doesn't GCC force parameters in __attribute__((pure)) functions to be const?

Tags: c++, attributes

The following code compiles without warnings under GCC 4.2, and as far as I can tell, it really shouldn't:

```
#include <fstream>

__attribute__((pure))
double UnpureFunction(double* x) {
  x[0] = 42;
  return 43;
}

int main () {
  double x[] = {0};
  double y = UnpureFunction(x);
  printf("%.2f %.2f\n", x[0], y);
}
```

(It prints "42.00 43.00".)

As I understand it, the pure attribute tells the compiler that the function has no external effects (see the section on "pure" [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)). But UnpureFunction is modifying its parameter. Why is this allowed to happen? At the very minimum, the compiler could automatically make every parameter const.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, `pure` is *your* promise to the compiler, but it won't try and verify that you're not lying.
Even if it did force parameters to be `const`, those parameters could be lying (e.g. an object might have a mutable member that's modified when your code calls a member function).

If you're looking for const correctness, use `const` parameters. The `pure` and `const` attributes are there to provide hints that can be used for optimization.

Comment: This is ridiculous. What is the point of having an attribute if there is no way to enforce it? I'm myself trying to find a way to tell gcc that a function is not allowed to access any variables outside of it's arguments but so far I have not found a way to abort compilation if this rule is broken. You would imagine that something this simply would be standard in 2019....

Answer (score 1):

First, if the function is forwarding the const/non-const of its parameters, then the function could still be pure, and some later function will modify it. That is the non-const reference doesn't dictate that the function specifically will modify it, but rather a non-const reference grants the access that some operation, down the chain, will modify the state(ie produce side effects). For example, if I want to write a function that returns the first element of a vector of ints:

```
int& first(std::vector<int>& v) __attribute__((pure))
{
    return *(v.begin());
}
```

I can declare it as pure even though it may take a non-const reference, because `first()` doesn't modify the vector. Instead it only retrieves the first element(generally that doesn't produce side effects). Some operation later on could modify the value. In this sense it is only forwarding the const/non-const of the range.

Secondly, even though the parameters are `const`, it still doesn't guarantee that there are no side effect, since a `class` can declare fields as modifiable even when the class is `const`, using the keyword `mutable`.

Answer (score -2):

Ah, dumb question. The __attribute__((pure)) construct allows the programmer to use pointers as output variables, as is standard. I guess this means I can't avoid lots of boilerplate consts in front of my variables.